# Kernel Regression

Tags: kernel-trick, ridge-regression

In Kernel Regression with a linear kernel, we have
$$\beta = X\alpha = X^T(XX^T+\lambda I)^{-1}Y$$
and the normal Ridge Regression solution is
$$\beta = (X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TY.$$
How can you prove that $X^T(XX^T+\lambda I)^{-1} = (X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^T$?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with

$$
(X^TX)X^T + \lambda IX^T = (X^TX)X^T + \lambda IX^T 
$$

Use the associativity of matrix multiplication, and the fact that multiplication with a diagonal matrix is commutative, to obtain

$$
(X^TX)X^T + \lambda IX^T = X^T(XX^T) + X^T\lambda I 
$$

Using distributivity of addition / multiplication,

$$
(X^TX + \lambda I)X^T = X^T(XX^T + \lambda I)
$$

for $\lambda > 0$, the matrices in the parentheses are positive definite and have an inverse. Simply multiply both sides on the left by $(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}$ and on the right by $(XX^T + \lambda I)^{-1}$.